# Query trick - kind of unpivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following table

```
SnapShotDay OperationalUnitNumber   IsOpen      StatusDate
1-01-2014       001                   1         1-01-2014
2-01-2014       NULL                NULL           NULL
3-01-2014       001                   0         3-01-2014
4-01-2014       NULL                NULL           NULL
5-01-2014       001                   1         5-01-2014
```

I obtain this with a SELECT construct, but what I need to do now is fill in the "NULL"ed rows by taking values from the first Non nulled row before. The latter would give:

```
SnapShotDay OperationalUnitNumber   IsOpen      StatusDate
1-01-2014       001                   1         1-01-2014
2-01-2014       001                   1         1-01-2014
3-01-2014       001                   0         3-01-2014
4-01-2014       001                   0         3-01-2014
5-01-2014       001                   1         5-01-2014
```

In functional words: I have events records that give me an event on a date for an oprrational unit; the event is: IsOpen or IsClosed. Chaining those events together according to the date gives a sort of **Ranges**. What I need is generate daily records for those ranges (target is a fact table).
I am trying to achieve this in plain SQL query (no stored procedure).

Can you think of a trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @t table(
    SnapShotDay date, 
    OperationalUnitNumber int,   
    IsOpen bit, 
    StatusDate date
)

insert into @t
select '1-01-2014',       001 , 1 , '1-01-2014' union all
select '2-01-2014',       NULL, NULL, NULL union all
select '3-01-2014',       001 , 0 ,'3-01-2014' union all
select '4-01-2014',       NULL,NULL,NULL union all
select '5-01-2014',       001 ,1,'5-01-2014'
;
with CTE as
(
    select *,row_number()over( order by (select 0))rn from @t
)
select *,
case when a.isopen is null then (
        select IsOpen from cte where rn=a.rn-1
    ) else a.isopen end 
from cte a
```

> ok i got it create one more cte1 then,

```
,cte1 as
(
select top 1 rn ,IsOpen from cte where IsOpen is not null order by rn desc
)
--select * from Statuses
select *,
    case 
        when a.rn<=(select b.rn from cte1 b)  and a.IsOpen is null then 
            (
                select 
                    a1.IsOpen 
                from 
                    cte a1

                where 
                    a1.rn=a.rn-1 
            ) 
         when a.rn>=(select b.rn from cte1 b) and  a.IsOpen is null then
         (select IsOpen from cte1)
        else 
        a.isopen 
    end 
from 
    cte a
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have a weird issue.. I do not seem to understand it, the select of the isopen flag stops at some point, and NULLs are returned as shown in : http://pastebin.com/vCRCysXu

Comment: @CoolStraw ok i got it ?what will happen if last rows are null ?

Comment: the flag can never be NULL, it is either 0 or 1. Same goes for the operational unit key as it is a business key in the framework of what am doing :-). Thx for the addition will try it out !

Comment: @CoolStraw,then there was no problem.Problem was in your dummy data,which was producing null in the last rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In the main query we're looking for the previous date with not null values. Then just JOIN this table with this `LastDate`.

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
  SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(SnapShotDay) 
                    FROM T 
                    WHERE SnapShotDay<=TMain.SnapShotDay
                          AND OPERATIONALUNITNUMBER IS NOT NULL) 
             as LastDate
  FROM T as TMain
 )

  SELECT T1.SnapShotDay,
         T.OperationalUnitNumber,
         T.IsOpen,
         T.StatusDate 
    FROM T1
    JOIN T ON T1.LastDate=T.SnapShotDay
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/746b7/3)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the trick ! except that it won't work... the problem is I have multiple operational Unit :-/ therefore I think partitioning by it is mandatory... trying to get the right way to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.SnapShotDay,
    CASE WHEN t1.OperationalUnitNumber IS NOT NUll 
        THEN t1.OperationalUnitNumber 
        ELSE  (SELECT TOP 1 t2.OperationalUnitNumber FROM  YourTable t2 WHERE t2.SnapShotDay < t1.SnapShotDay AND t2.OperationalUnitNumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SnapShotDay DESC)
    END AS OperationalUnitNumber,
    CASE WHEN t1.IsOpen IS NOT NUll 
        THEN t1.IsOpen 
        ELSE  (SELECT TOP 1 t2.IsOpen FROM  YourTable t2 WHERE t2.SnapShotDay < t1.SnapShotDay AND t2.IsOpen IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SnapShotDay DESC)
    END AS IsOpen,  
    CASE WHEN t1.StatusDate IS NOT NUll 
        THEN t1.StatusDate 
        ELSE  (SELECT TOP 1 t2.StatusDate FROM  YourTable t2 WHERE t2.SnapShotDay < t1.SnapShotDay AND t2.StatusDate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SnapShotDay DESC)
    END AS StatusDate
FROM YourTable t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for 'plain sql', here is a tested attempt using SQL, with comments, that gives the required answer.

I have tested the code using 'sqlite' and 'mysql' on windows xp. It is pure SQL and should work everywhere.

SQL is about 'sets' and combining them and ordering the results.

This problem seems to be about two separate sets:

1) The 'snap shot day' that have readings.

2) the 'snap shot day' that don't have readings.

I have added extra columns so that we can easily see where values came from.

let us deal with the easy set first:

This is the set of 'supplied' readings.

```
SELECT dss.SnapShotDay theDay, 
       'supplied'  readingExists,       
       dss.OperationalUnitNumber,
       dss.IsOpen,       
       dss.StatusDate       
FROM dailysnapshot dss
WHERE dss.OperationalUnitNumber IS NOT NULL
```

results:

```
theDay      readingExists   OperationalUnitNumber   IsOpen  StatusDate
2014-01-01  supplied        001                     1       2014-01-01
2014-01-03  supplied        001                     0       2014-01-03
2014-01-05  supplied        001                     1       2014-01-05
```

Now let us deal with the set of 'days that have missing readings'. We need to get the 'most recent day that has readings that is closest to the day with the missing readings' and assume the same values from the 'most recent day' that is before the 'current' missing day.

It sounds complex but it isn't. It asks:
foreach day without a reading - get me the closest, earlier, date that has readings and i will use those readings.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT emptyDSS.SnapShotDay,  
       'missing'  readingExists,       
       maxPrevDSS.OperationalUnitNumber,
       maxPrevDSS.IsOpen,       
       maxPrevDSS.StatusDate       
FROM dailysnapshot emptyDSS
  INNER JOIN dailysnapshot maxPrevDSS ON maxPrevDSS.SnapShotDay = 
                                                 (SELECT MAX(dss.SnapShotDay)
                                                  FROM   dailysnapshot dss
                                                  WHERE  dss.SnapShotDay < emptyDSS.SnapShotDay
                                                  AND    dss.OperationalUnitNumber IS NOT NULL)                                                  
WHERE emptyDSS.OperationalUnitNumber IS NULL
```

results:

```
SnapShotDay readingExists   OperationalUnitNumber   IsOpen  StatusDate
2014-01-02  missing         001                     1       2014-01-01
2014-01-04  missing         001                     0       2014-01-03
```

This is not about efficiency! It is about getting the correct 'result set' with the easiest to understand SQL code. I assume the database engine will optimize the query. The query can be 'tweaked' later if required.

We now need to combine the two queries and order the results in the manner we require.

The standard way of combining results from SQL queries is with set operators (union, intersection, minus).

we use 'union' and an 'order by' on the result set.

**this gives the final query of:**

```
SELECT dss.SnapShotDay theDay, 
       'supplied'  readingExists,       
       dss.OperationalUnitNumber,
       dss.IsOpen,       
       dss.StatusDate       
FROM dailysnapshot dss
WHERE `OperationalUnitNumber` IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT emptyDSS.SnapShotDay theDay,  
       'missing'  readingExists,       
       maxPrevDSS.OperationalUnitNumber,
       maxPrevDSS.IsOpen,       
       maxPrevDSS.StatusDate       
FROM dailysnapshot emptyDSS
  INNER JOIN dailysnapshot maxPrevDSS ON  maxPrevDSS.SnapShotDay = 
                                                 (SELECT MAX(dss.SnapShotDay)
                                                  FROM   dailysnapshot dss
                                                  WHERE  dss.SnapShotDay < emptyDSS.SnapShotDay
                                                  AND    dss.OperationalUnitNumber IS NOT NULL)
WHERE emptyDSS.OperationalUnitNumber IS NULL
ORDER BY theDay ASC
```

result:

```
theDay      readingExists   dss.OperationalUnitNumber  dss.IsOpen  dss.StatusDate
2014-01-01  supplied        001                        1           2014-01-01
2014-01-02  missing         001                        1           2014-01-01
2014-01-03  supplied        001                        0           2014-01-03
2014-01-04  missing         001                        0           2014-01-03
2014-01-05  supplied        001                        1           2014-01-05
```

I enjoyed doing this.

It should work with most SQL engines.